Should one avoid a memory allocation practice that forces a single malloc call?
I wonder if allocating memory for all the data related to a struct is a good practice. So, let's say that we have the following struct, which aims to store arrays of float-arrays:
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Arrays {
    int n;
    int* l;
    double** data;
} Arrays;

One can initialize an example like this:
Arrays* UsualInitialization(int n) {
    // Constructs an array A of length n containing the arrays A[i] = [1,2,...,i]
    Arrays* A = (Arrays*) malloc(sizeof(Arrays*));
    A->n = n;
    A->l = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    A->data = (double**) malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A->l[i] = i + 1;
        A->data[i] = (double*) malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(double));
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
            A->data[i][j] = j + 1;
    }

    return A;
}

Every pointer has a corresponding malloc call. But we can also do something like this:
Arrays* BlockInitialization(int n) {
    // Constructs an array A of length n containing the arrays A[i] = [1,2,...,i]
    Arrays* A = (Arrays*) malloc(sizeof(Arrays) + 
                    n * sizeof(int) + 
                    n * sizeof(double*) +
                    (n * (n+1) / 2) * sizeof(double)
    );
    
    A->n = n;
    A->l = (int*) (A + 1);
    A->data = (double**) (A->l + n);
    A->data[0] = (double*) (A->data + n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A->l[i] = i + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) 
            A->data[i][j] = j + 1;
        if (i < n - 1)
            A->data[i+1] = A->data[i] + i + 1;
    }

    return A;
}

Here, there's a single malloc call, and all the other pointers are obtained from the first one by pointer arithmetic and casting. I figure this might be more efficient in certain cases since all the allocated memory is in a single block.
So, I'd like to ask: does this practice incur in undefined behavior? Does it affect performance (in some cases)? Does it make the code more obscure?
I leave below a print method and a main that show that both initializations give the same result (at least in my machine).
void PrintArrays(Arrays* A) {
    printf("Variable contains %d arrays: \n", A->n);
    for (int i = 0; i < A->n; i++) {
        printf("Array %d (of length %d): [", i, A->l[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < A->l[i]; j++) {
            printf("%f", A->data[i][j]);
            if (j < A->l[i] - 1)  printf(", ");
        }
        printf("] \n");
    }
}

int main() {
    Arrays* A = BlockInitialization(10);
    PrintArrays(A);

    Arrays* B = UsualInitialization(10);
    PrintArrays(B);

    return 0;
}


It definitely makes the code more obscure. :-) It also makes it hard to know which pointers should be free'd at the end. When allocating a 2D array of doubles, I would expect the computations that follow to take much more time than the memory allocations. So is this really a hotspot?

I would eliminate the needless cast and reduce coupling: Arrays* a = malloc(sizeof *a + sizeof a->l + sizeof a->data + (sizeof *a->data) * count).  But ultimately the choice may be determined by whether those data will remain associated for their whole lifetime, and whether you can track which Arrays have the combined allocations so that you can call the appropriate free().  And don't forget to consider alignment - you might be safer with a wrapper - struct ArrayWithData { Arrays a; int l, double data[]; }

If Arrays is your own type, and you always want to allocate as a block, then perhaps you need to re-think which members are pointers (and remember the option of a flexible array member).

@TobySpeight You mean that maybe I should declare data as double[] and use the variable l to indicate the "beginning" of the A[i] in data? With this, I cna use flexible array members. I don't see the advantage of a wrapper :(

The wrapper is only useful if the Arrays structure is not under your control (e.g. if it's defined by a library you're using).  If you can modify Arrays, you don't need a wrapper - just change the pointer members into ordinary data object members.

@TobySpeight By the way, you wrote sizeof *a + sizeof a->l +..., but should it be sizeof *a + n * sizeof *a->l + n * sizeof *a->data + count * sizeof *a->data? What I understand is that sizeof *a allocates memory for one int, one int* and one double**. Then, we need extra for the values a->l[i], the values a->data[i], and the values a->data[i][j].

1 allocation is nearly always better than many of them. Allocations are rather expensive (and do not scale either). If you do not change the size of the sub-arrays and do not benefit from the double* types, then there is no benefit of using jagged arrays like you do. Besides, if your real-wold code use such sub-array sizes, then you can perform further optimizations. There is no need to even store the start-stop indices since 1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2. In this case, you can eventually just write typedef struct Arrays { int n; double* data; } (and possibly use flexible array members).

Oh, sorry, I missed that l points to n elements.


So, I'd like to ask: does this practice incur in undefined behavior?

Not if you do it correctly.
The only obvious issue here is that for odd n, the final pointers and doubles could be misaligned. You need to use alignof to figure out how much padding is needed between consecutive members.

Does it affect performance (in some cases)?

Yes, it can make the performance much better on platforms which benefit from cache-friendly memory layouts.
It'll probably be even better if you lose all the pointers, remove the 1d array and flatten the 2d array, and provide simple accessors to get/index the array(s).
Even redundant-looking offset calculations are typically faster than multiple chained pointer dereferences. (Also, removing the pointers makes the data even more compact and cache-friendly).
The minimal version is just
struct LowerTriangular
{
  int order;
  double data[];
};

and as a bonus, this also saves you from managing the alignment.

Does it make the code more obscure?

Yes, but if the obscure bit is encapsulated in two functions (allocator and deallocator), you can comment it well, test it thoroughly, and then forget about it.

Thank you, the explanation is very clear.

Depending on the platform, it might not be only odd n that cause misalignment, and not only of the pointers and doubles.  In the theoretical worst case, those casts could all be misaligned for all values of n.

Good point - every size (and offset) needs to be rounded to the alignment of the following type.

Focus on correct functionality before seeking optimization
In OP's quest to optimize, incorrect code was made:
Arrays* A = (Arrays*) malloc(sizeof(Arrays*)); // Bad - why the size of a pointer?

When allocating, instead of using an unnecessary cast and sizing to a type (which was wrong above), drop the cast and size to the referenced object:
Arrays* A = malloc(sizeof A[0]);
// or 
Arrays* A = malloc(sizeof *A);


All at once allocation failed to insure alignment.  OP computation did not account for potential alignment needs.
// Bad
sizeof(Arrays) + n * sizeof(int) + n * sizeof(double*) + (n * (n+1) / 2) * sizeof(double)

When the implementation supports variable lengths arrays and n > 0, form a pointer to a struct of all the allocations to easily get the padding and alignment of all arrays.
// Constructs an array A of length n containing the arrays A[i] = [1,2,...,i]
Arrays* BlockInitialization_alt(int n) {
    assert(n > 0);
    struct {
      Arrays A;
      int l[n];
      double *data[n];
      double d[n * ((size_t)n+1) / 2]; 
    } *all = malloc(sizeof all[0]);
    if (all == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }

    Arrays* A = &all->A;
    A->n = n;
    A->l = &all->l;
    A->data = &all->data;

    double *d = &all->d;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A->l[i] = i + 1;
        A->data[i] = d;
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
            A->data[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
        d += i + 1;
    }
    return A;
}


This is the first time I see a struct declaration inside a function. What are the implications? For example, is it more time expensive to declare this struct inside the function or to do the padding calculations on my own?

@RB1995 Note that all is a pointer to a struct.  As the struct contains variable length arrays, its size varies between function calls. "padding calculations on my own?" is prone to error and will not be faster.

Yes, all is a pointer, I understand that part. My question is actually about what happens behind the scenes. What happens when you define the struct inside the function? Sorry if this is a very basic question, I'm just learning C. The original question was in fact about understanding the language better. If you have any reference to learn more that'd be great!
